# How to make a core-element apps icon behave like that in google email apps icon

Tags: dart-polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

Is it possible to use core-element and/or paper-element to get a core-element apps icon to behave like the one on Google mail as shown in the graphic.

I don't see any core- or paper-elements with such a 'dialog' with a pointer pointing towards the apps icon.[image]

By 'behaving' I mean its appearance/disappearance when clicked as well as the container used.

Comment: The 'pointer' seems to be an image; it's placement doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks. If I use a dialog the popup is not as flat when the apps icon is clicked. Is there anyway to keep it 'flat'?